# Finding volume raise/lower command(s)

Tags: lubuntu, pulseaudio, alsa, shortcut-keys

I'm using Lubuntu 13.04 and am looking for the command to raise and lower my volume in increments so I can add that command to my lubuntu-rc.xml file thus binding it to my XF86AudioRaiseVolume (i.e. Fn+Uparrow) key. Right now, according to the lubuntu-rc.xml file, the Fn+Uparrow combination executes `amixer -q set Master 3%+ unmute`, but when I type this command in the terminal I get the error message `amixer: Unable to find simple control 'Master',0`.

I've looked at similar questions, but they've availed me nothing. I really don't understand ALSA (nor PulseAudio).

Comment: Run `amixer controls`.

Comment: @CL. OUTPUT: `quinn@quinn-Aspire-V5-121:~$ amixer controls
numid=1,iface=CARD,name='HDMI/DP,pcm=3 Jack'
numid=2,iface=MIXER,name='IEC958 Playback Con Mask'
numid=3,iface=MIXER,name='IEC958 Playback Pro Mask'
numid=4,iface=MIXER,name='IEC958 Playback Default'
numid=5,iface=MIXER,name='IEC958 Playback Switch'
numid=6,iface=PCM,name='ELD',device=3
numid=7,iface=PCM,name='Playback Channel Map',device=3`

Comment: Your default card is the GPU's HDMI output. Add the `-c 1` parameter.

Comment: @CL. That basically worked, save the following 3 issues: 1. The volume decrease command, `amixer -c 1 -q sset Master 1%- unmute`, command will only decrease the volume to 8 (not 0), 2. the volume increase and decrease commands do not unmute (even though each ends with the text `unmute`, and 3. the `amixer -c 1 -q sset Master toggle` command, which is supposed to toggle mute, only mutes (it does not unmute).

Comment: @CL. I'm gonna post my new issues in a new question. If you transmute your (second) comment to an answer, I'll accept it. In any case, thanks much.

Comment: @CL. I've asked my follow up queestion [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/350433/raise-lower-volume-commands-only-work-in-range-8-100-mute-command-doesnt-toggl).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem (error: amixer: Unable to find simple control 'Master',0).

When I added `-c 1`, the volume increase and decrease commands do not unmute and the toogle command (mute / unmute) does not unmute.

In another post, I found that adding `-D pulse` instead of `-c 1` then all of the commands are OK (increase and unmute, decrease and unmute, toogle).

```
amixer -D pulse -q sset Master 3%+ unmute
amixer -D pulse -q sset Master 3%- unmute
amixer -D pulse -q sset Master toggle
```